# Does deleting an answer remove the negative points to your reputation?

Tags: discussion, answers

I answered a question, but it doesn't follow with the majority's conjecture and is being downvoted.  Should I just delete my answer?  And if I do, will that reverse the negative reputation points?

Comment: Why do you assume that it's being downvoted just because it "doesn't follow with the majority's conjecture"? Maybe it's not well-supported by evidence, or needs sources, or is too short or confusingly written. When I downvote answers, it's usually through the review queues; I don't even see the other answers, so I downvote for one of those reasons, not because it's out of sync with the other answers.

Comment: If you want to try improving your answer instead of deleting it, you can make another meta post with a link to your answer and ask for advice. Since we're a small site, asking for advice and making improvements usually gets enough attention that people will come and reverse their downvotes.

Comment: I'm basically with Dimitri's answer, but it would require more work to improve your answer and to backup your claim. (I can see another detail in the pictures that hasn't been mentioned yet, which supports the other answers.) Even though I liked parts of your answer and I can see that you put considerable effort into it I will be downvoting your answer as it currently is and thus giving you a chance to earn a badge. I would be happier though to see more structure in your answer and understanding that it's not subjective bias why you received negative votes.

Comment: Thank you very much for commenting on my question.  I have gone back to the episode in question and reviewed it several times and I am now ready to edit my previous answer.  After I have done so, I will follow Torisuda's advice and post it to the Meta asking for advice.  @LiveWireBT - what did you mean when you said you were 'giving me a chance to earn a badge'?

Comment: @Jinoshio http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure

Comment: @LiveWireBT - lol, thanks!  But, that's not a badge to strive for...I think.  :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes reputation is restored if you delete the question [How is reputation archived](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/)

***But*** much rather than deleting, you should try to improve your answer if possible instead. You can ask for a clarification in the comments from the down voters, in the chat, or even on meta.

So while we are at it. [lets review your answer a bit](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/30826/1458)

The answer on it self is not that bad, but it lacks sources. A theory is good and all, but try to back it up using source materials, statements they made, visuals or even the statements the author himself has give.

If you are unsure how you could do this, then take an example on the other given answers. Whom base it on the characters hair color/length, physical traits, introduced characters and the likes.

Don't let a few down-votes get to you. Just keep on answering, and try to improve your answers as you go.